# load() inside modal-body firing multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a script that opens a bootstrap modal, then you confirm your selection with an "im sure" button, then that post()'s and if it submits successfully it load's a comment form into the modal-body. The comment form is stored in a partial, and the comment for uses wysihtml5. Here is my current code:

```
    modal_div.find('.confirm-o-c').click(function(ee){
            $.post(
                lnk.attr('href'),
                function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
                    console.log(data);

                    var lbl = lnk.parent().prev().children('.label').first();
                    lbl.fadeOut('fast');
                    lbl.attr('class','label label-'+data.status)
                       .text(data.text)
                       .fadeIn('fast');
                    var newlnk = $('<a href="#">newlink</a>');
                    newlnk.attr('href',lnk.attr('href').replace('complete','revert'));
                    lnk.parent().append(newlnk);
                    lnk.remove();
                    var status = data.status;
                    var id = data.object.id;
                    var objective_id = data.object.objective_id;

                    if(status === 'submitted'){
                        modal.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                            modal.load('<?=URL::to_action('objectives/completion_comment/')?>/'+id, function(){  
                                modal.fadeIn('fast');
                                $('#message-'+objective_id).wysihtml5();

                            });

                            $('#confirm-objective-complete').addClass('modal-large');
                            $('#submit-comment').css("display", "inline-block");
                            oldfooterbtn.css("display", "none");
                            footerbtncancel.css("display", "none"); 
                            footerbtnclose.css("display", "none");  
                            confirmtext.css("display", "none");                 
                        });
                    };

                });
            // objectives.init();
            ee.preventDefault();
```

**The problem**
After confirming, the post works great, and it returns submitted, but then when the comment form is leaded it my console shows it happening like 8 times and I get this error
`TypeError: f.contentWindow is null`

I have seen some like:

```
    $(this).one('load', function () {
        console.log("load complete");
    });'
```

but I couldn't figure our how to implement using a URL like I am. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for looking over my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due the the variable modal being set to `$('.modal-body')` while their where multiple instiances of that in the DOM. once I narrowed it down to `var modal = modal_div.find('.modal-body');` it was able to select only the current modal-body.

Answer (score 0):

Like this : http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(this).load('myurl/page',{/*JSON data*/},function () {
    console.log("load complete");
});'
```

Comment: I am already doing this. My question is why is load firing multiple times. also in my question i was asking how to use a URL, with the .one('load', fucntion{})

Comment: About .one() => $(this).one('load', {url : url}, function () {});

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not binding multiple events to the modal. 
You can clear it with the unbind function, specially if are binding events to it multiple times:

```
$('#myModal').unbind();
```